# Rider "Android Sdk not found" even though it is there

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, rider, android-sdk-2.3

Hi there today I reset my pc and installed Rider and over the Settings/Environment the Xamarin Android and Xamarin iOS Sdk. As I wanted to create a new Xamarin.Forms project Rider said that the Android Sdk is missing. So I switched to the settings downloaded the Sdk and applied it to Rider. But it didn't work. I even have installed the Android Ndk.

This is what the Rider NewProject Window looks like:
[image]

And this is what the Rider Settings look like when I press on the "Open settings and install Android SDK" link:
[image]

So why is this. Is there somethings I've done wrong?

This is what the Android Sdk Folder looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Problem**

Oh I have just found the problem. If you hover the "?" next to the Error-Link you can see following popup:

[image]

And I have installed **Android SDK API 31** which is apparently not supported.

**Solution**

Simply install **Android Sdk API 30**.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Mac and especially ARM.

I had the same problem (I have installed Android SDK API 34 but which is currently unusable)

**Solution**

([Installed JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/))

- Started JetBrains Toolbox
- Installed Android Studio
- Started Android Studio
- Selected 'More Actions'
- Selected SDK Manager
- Select the Version you want to install and which also is getting supported by your Rider version
- Now Press on Apply, install it and you are good to go